# Sinatra database-based sessions

Tags: session, heroku, sinatra

I'm currently using Sinatra with Heroku, and the only synchronization is the database. Therefore, I need sessions that are stored in a database (hopefully not using ActiveRecord).

Is there a Rack middleware, or something else to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [**`Moneta` gem**](https://github.com/minad/moneta) as an alternative session manager for Sinatra.

Straight from their GitHub page:

> Moneta provides a standard interface for interacting with various kinds of key/value stores...

Setup Moneta as a Rack session store:

```ruby
# in your config.ru
require 'rack/session/moneta'

# Use only the adapter name
use Rack::Session::Moneta, :store => :Redis

# Use Moneta.new
use Rack::Session::Moneta, :store => Moneta.new(:Memory, :expires => true)

# Use the Moneta builder
use Rack::Session::Moneta do
  use :Expires
  adapter :Memory
end
```

It works with almost anything you can think of: file-based and in-memory stores, ActiveRecord, Sequel, DataMapper, Memcached, REDIS, CouchDB, MongoDB, and more.

#### Update

To elaborate on integration with your `Rack` app, this is how my `config.ru` is set up on a production site running on Heroku and using [Redis Cloud](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud) add-on:

```ruby
if ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym == :production
    use Rack::Session::Moneta,
        key:            'domain.name',
        domain:         '.example.com',
        path:           '/',
        expire_after:   7*24*60*60, # one week
        secret:         ENV['PRODUCTION_SESSION_SECRET_KEY'],

        store:          Moneta.new(:Redis, {
            url:            ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'],
            expires:        true,
            threadsafe:     true
        })
else
    use Rack::Session::Moneta,
        key:            'domain.name',
        domain:         '*',
        path:           '/',
        expire_after:   30*24*60*60, # one month
        secret:         ENV['DEV_SESSION_SECRET_KEY'],

        store:          Moneta.new(:Redis, {
            url:            ENV['DEV_REDIS_URL'],
            expires:        true,
            threadsafe:     true
        })
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was asking for!

Comment: Do you need to define all 3? I want to setup redis. I used an example that was in the site which is: https://gist.github.com/61dabb63d4333bb83eba but I am having nearly 100 entries for every session storage.

Comment: No, just one is enough, my example just shows different ways of using it. If you're running on Shotgun, each linked asset  _may_ generate a fresh session, so that could be the reason. Check your logs and post a new question if you're having a different issues.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using database for session store, you can use [memcache add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/memcachier) on Heroku. You can read about it in [memcachier documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier)

Sinatra snippet to configure memcache as session store

```
require 'rack/session/dalli'

mem_serv, mem_uname, mem_pword = ENV['MEMCACHIER_SERVERS'], ENV['MEMCACHIER_USERNAME'], ENV['MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD']
cache = Dalli::Client.new(mem_serv, {:username => mem_uname, :password => mem_pword})
use Rack::Session::Dalli, :cache => $cache
```

IMO memcache as a session store makes much more sense than using Database. Other alternative that I can think of is Redis as session store.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will consider this solution as well.

Comment: P.S. You can use Memcached with `Moneta` as well, and you still can take advantage of `Moneta`'s nice DSL.

Comment: I was not aware of `Moneta`, looks very useful. Are you aware of any drawback in using it instead of `Dalli`? Further I guess, it can be used for `Iron cache` as well.